# なぜubuntuは14系と16系が主流なんでしょうか

Tags: ubuntu

ubuntuを最近触り始めました。
14系と16系を別々のサーバーで運用しています。

ずっと気になっていたのですが、15系が無かったことにされてるような印象を受けます。
何故ですか?

Answer (score 9):

LTSである14系と16系は5年サポート、そうでない15系は9ヶ月のサポート期間です。つまり15系を使えば9ヶ月以内にはアップグレードすることになるわけですが、サーバー用途でこれは面倒な話です。
<sub>（なのでデスクトップ用途なら15系も使われていたのではないでしょうか）</sub>

またサーバー用途なら Ubuntu Server としてインストールしていると思いますが、Ubuntu Server のダウンロードページではLTS版より新しい非LTS版がある時でも両方をダウンロードページに載せ、LTS版を推奨するような記述をしています。

例 [15系がリリースされたころの Ubuntu Server のダウンロードページ](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160101152638/http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)

いずれにせよ非LTSバージョンが話題に上るのは半年～9か月ということになりますから、5年間使われ続けるLTSの方が、ネット上にも多くの情報があるように思います。

Answer (score 6):

14、16にはLTSがあり、15には無いからではないでしょうか。
LTSのリリースは２年毎です。また通常版のサポート期間はリリースから９ヶ月であるのに対して、LTS(14.04、16.04)では５年です。（14系でも通常版の14.10はサポート期間が終了していますが･･･）

https://www.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu